# how to compare filenames, then classify uniquely from folder into ListBox if repeated

Tags: c#, file, listbox, classification, listboxitem

I have json files that i'm trying to classify so the file names are as such:

```
 inputTestingSetting_test
 inputTestingSetting_test1310
 inputTestingSetting_test1310_ckf
 inputTestingSetting_test1310_ols
 inputTestingSetting_test1310_sum
 inputTestingSetting_test1311_ckf
 inputTestingSetting_test1311_ols
 inputTestingSetting_test1311_sum
```

So the output that i want in the ListBox lbJsonFileNames will be

```
test
test1310
test1311
```

currently my codes are

```
 DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(tbJSFolder.Text);
        FileInfo[] Files = dInfo.GetFiles("*.json");
        List<jSonName> jsonName = new List<jSonName>();
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            string[] fileNameSplit = filename.Split('_');


                jsonName = new List<jSonName>{
                new jSonName(fileNameSplit[0],fileNameSplit[1])
            };
            for(int i=0;i<jsonName.Count;i++)
            {
                if(jsonName[i].TestNumber == fileNameSplit[1])
                {
                    lbJsonFileNames.Items.Add(jsonName[i].TestNumber);
                }
            }
        }
```

so my output for `lbJsonFileNames` is what i want, however it is repeated. is it possible to just show one? i've tried to put `jsonName[i].TestNumber` to `jsonName[i+1].TestNumber`. but failed as it is out of range.

is there a way to read the file names, and then compare it with the previous file name to see if it is the same? and if it is the same, ignore, move on to the next file name, if it's different then it is added into the ListBox

changed my codes to

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(tbJSFolder.Text);
        FileInfo[] Files = dInfo.GetFiles("*.json");
        List<jSonName> jsonName = new List<jSonName>();
        HashSet<string> fileNames = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            string[] fileNameSplit = filename.Split('_');
            fileNames.Add(fileNameSplit[1]);

        }
        foreach(var value in fileNames)
        {
            lbJsonFileNames.Items.Add(value);
        }
```

got what i want now thanks all~

Comment: no i have not, and i have no idea what that is, i'll go read about it now. ahaha

Comment: Try replace the "inputTestingSetting_" to string.Empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically says to put the following into list box:

```
test
test1310
test1310
test1310
test1310
test1311
test1311
test1311
```

Before you add as in `lbJsonFileNames.Items.Add(jsonName[i].TestNumber);`, check for duplicate first. Maybe you can put that list into a `Set` variable. Set will automatically remove the duplicate. Then put the `Set` back to `lbJsonFileNames`.

[Edit] Sorry there is no `Set` in dot net. Please use `HashSet` instead.[/Edit]

Comment: by `Set` you mean the get set that Set?

Comment: O. There is only `HashSet` in dot net. Please use `HashSet` instead.

Comment: omg. yaye thanks i finally realised how to use `HashSet` it's like `List` thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not mention what **jSonName** class is like and the constructor parameters stand for. However to **get your output from your input** can be much easier:

```
        string[] all = Directory.GetFiles(tbJSFolder.Text, "*.json")
            .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
            .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '_' })[1])
            .Distinct().ToArray();
        lbJsonFileNames.Items.AddRange(all);
```

Comment: oh yeah just tried this and it works as well. is there a name for this sorta code? or it;s like, manipulating the data in an array?

Comment: ohh okay thanks! :) i think i'll stick to the HashSet cause Linq seems a little complicated for me haha